# Match "any" but not array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have a function typed to return `any` but not an `array`.

Something like this:

`Not<any, any[]>`

```
interface Specific {
  name: string;
}

const makeOneCore = (): any => {
  return {};
};

const makeManyCore = (): any[] => {
  return [{}];
};

const makeOne = (): Specific => {
  return makeOneCore();
};

const makeMany = (): Specific[] => {
  return makeManyCore();
};

const makeManyShouldFail = (): Specific[] => {
  return makeOneCore();
};
```

I would like to type `makeOneCore` so that `makeManyShouldFail` would be a typescript error, because it should matches `any` as being a possible `array`.

Looking for some way that `hello` is valid and `boom` is not.

```
type NotArray<T> = T extends Array<any> ? never: T;

type v = NotArray<Array<any>>;

const hello: v = {};
const boom: v = [];

console.log({ hello, boom });
```

Comment: It seems like you may want to use generics `makeOneCore<T> = (): T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
type NotArray<T> = T extends Array<any> ? never: T;

type A = NotArray<Array<any>>; // never
type B = NotArray<Array<string>>; // never
type C = NotArray<boolean>; // boolean
```

type `never` can to be assign to any other type

Comment: Just tried this and it's not working as expected, added some more context in the question above.

Comment: `type v = NotArray<Array<any>>;` is the same as `type v = never;` because is executed once. Try something like this `let hello: NotArray<{}>; // {}` `let boom: NotArray<{}>; // never`